# Python: Ping Test before doing anything

Tags: python, ping

I am currently trying to check if I got internet Connection before I do something but even though I Ping a Connection, and it should not jump into the If it still does.

```
ipaddress = '8.8.8.8'
ipaddress2 = '8.8.4.4'
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ipaddress)
response2 = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ipaddress2)

if response or response2 == 0:
    do something
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Daweo I use Linux

Comment: Try running it in a bash shell and see what happens if you deliberately use a non-existent IP address. On macOS the following will return a value of 2. ping -c 1 -t 1 88.8.8.8 >/dev/null; echo $?

Comment: It's also worth noting that your code won't necessarily achieve your objective. The IP addresses you've specified are the Google public DNS servers. If, for some reason, those servers were unavailable then that doesn't indicate whether you have a viable internet connection or not. It just means that you can't reach those addresses. You may be able to reach others.

Comment: @JCaesar I plugged the Internet from the server which I am using.  I think it should not jump into the If then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the Problem myself.

In Python you gotta put the Comparison behind every Variable.

Like this:

```
ipaddress = '8.8.8.8'
ipaddress2 = '8.8.4.4'
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ipaddress)
response2 = os.system("ping -c 1 " + ipaddress2)

if response == 0 or response2 == 0:
    do something
```

Comment: This is because os.system returns the system exit code of that command. In Linux exit 0, means the command completed succesfully